# w3c Document xpath does not return nodeset

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

Hello :) I want to have all `enumeration` nodes but length of the collection returns 0. In future I would need List of `enumeration.value` attributes, so for example currently it would one-element list with WOW inside. But the problem is that I cannot pick `enumeration` nodes at all.

The xml part:

```
<xs:complexType name="Code.Something">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:restriction base="xxx:Code">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="code" form="unqualified">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                     <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                        <xs:enumeration value="WOW">
                           <xs:annotation>
                              <xs:appinfo>
                                 <Test>ABC</Test>
                              </xs:appinfo>
                           </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:enumeration>
```

**This has length 1:**

```
((NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//*[local-name()='complexType'][@name='Code.Something']",
        doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)).getLength();
```

**This has length 0 - why ?:**

```
 ((NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//*[local-name()='complexType'][@name='Code.Something']/*[local-name()='enumeration']",
        doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)).getLength();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single slash between nodes (`node1/node2`) means that you want to select `node2` that is the *direct child of `node1`*. You need to use double slash `//` between nodes (`node1//node2`) to select `node2` that is *descendant of `node1`*:

```
//*[local-name()='complexType'][@name='Code.Something']//*[local-name()='enumeration']
```